# IBM Informix and ODBC Driver C#

Tags: informix

Is there an obvious to semi obvious problem with the connection string that I am attempting to use to connect to informix. I have been using the following guide and different parameters to attempt to build a connection

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.netpr.doc/ids_net_066.htm

I cannot use the .net native drivers for informix because of the drda protocol requirement. I can build a system dsn and call it directly and it works great. I was trying to find out if I could skip the DSN setup in the ODBC manager and place it in the a config file instead. I am having a problem building a connection string that works using the 4.10 client. My connection string is as follows

string connStr ="CursorBehavior=0;Driver=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER;DB_LOCALE=en_US.819;Host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Server=; Service=31012; UID=informix; Password=xxxxxxx; Protocol=olsoctcp;DB=xxxx;Pooling=false";

The error is:
  Message=ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][-11302] Insufficient Connection information was supplied
ERROR [01S00] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid connection string attribute.
ERROR [01S00] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid connection string attribute.
ERROR [01S00] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid connection string attribute.
ERROR [01S00] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid connection string attribute.
ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][-11302] Insufficient Connection information was supplied

Comment: Informix does have a .NET set of drivers that use the `SQLI protocol` instead of `DRDA` ( [Differences between .NET Providers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.cliapinode.doc/netdif.htm) ).  For `ODBC`check if you are using the correct keywords ( [Connection string keywords that make a connection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.odbc.doc/ids_odbc_076.htm) ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a deliberate or accidental omission in your connection string but a value for the Server attribute is required. Not providing a value will most likely lead to the -11302 error. The value should correspond to either the DBSERVERNAME or one of the DBSERVERALIAS values specified in the Informix server's onconfig file and also match the entry in the server's sqlhosts file that uses tcp port 31012.

Comment: I intentionally scrubbed it from the string to prevent disclosing anything that would cause me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the driver name in curly braces as follows:

Driver = {IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER}; ...